# How to find the volume of a solid using integration bound by 4 equations?

Tags: integration, analysis, volume

The prompt is to find the volume of the solid bound by $z = x^2 + y^2$, $y = x^2$, $y = 1$ and $z = 0$.

[Here's what it looks like after being plotted](http://grapher.mathpix.com/?latexList=%5B%22z%5E2%3Dx%5E2%2By%5E2%22%2C%22y%3Dx%5E2%22%2C%22y%3D1%22%2C%22z%3D0%22%5D)

[image]

I am completely lost on how to find the limits and whether I should use triple or double integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection of your solid on the $xy$ plane is a parabolic segment and by symmetry

$$ V=2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x^2}^{1}\int_{0}^{x^2+y^2}1\,dz\,dy\,dx =2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x^2}^{1}x^2+y^2\,dy\,dx\tag{1}$$
$$ V = 2\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{3}+x^2-x^4-\frac{x^6}{3}\right)\,dx =2\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{21}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{88}{105}}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: Why is $0 < x < 1$ and not $-1 < x < 1$ like @Paul 's answer?

Comment: Where did the 2 taken out of integral came from?

Comment: @Ritwick: I said *symmetry*, meaning symmetry with respect to the plane $x=0$: the volume on the left equals the volume on the right, hence we may just compute the volume on the right of such plane.

Answer (score 1):

If you use triple integration, integrate 1 with the following limits.  $0 \le z \le x^2+y^2$, $x^2 \le y \le 1$, $-1 \le x \le 1$. Do you see why?